# Distinct Order Count by Date Range

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to figure out how to write a query to find out how many customers placed an order 1 time, 2 times etc within a given date range. The customers are identified with their unique email address and the orders should be the distinct order numbers.

Basically the data will show numerous order-ids per purchase because each line item gets it's own duplicate order-id...

The result should return 1 customer with 4 orders in the year. However it is not returning anything. Any help would be appreciated.

CURRENT QUERY (my database table is called amazon)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT amazon.`amazon-order-id`), amazon.`buyer-email` 
FROM amazon
WHERE amazon.`purchase-date` >= '1/1/2014' and
      amazon.`purchase-date` <= '12/31/2014'
GROUP BY amazon.`buyer-email`
HAVING COUNT(amazon.`amazon-order-id`) = 4
```

I am copying and pasting some sample data below:

```
*114-2021965-2390651    3/18/2014   svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*114-2021965-2390651    3/18/2014   svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*114-8957580-1296223    3/26/2014   svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*114-8957580-1296223    3/26/2014   svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*108-5564197-2113836    6/2/2014    svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*108-5564197-2113836    6/2/2014    svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*114-4685236-6299434    10/11/2014  svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com                                                                                                                                                                                      
*114-4685236-6299434    10/11/2014  svj8w3vj3x4y4k8@marketplace.ama4on.com
```

Comment: Remove the have clause

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data, your query worked once I added distinct to the
HAVING COUNT statement.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT amazon.amazon-order-id) = 4
```

Also the dates in your Sample Data caused me some trouble.
I had to add zeros to the single digit numbers, in order for the where clause to work correctly. I'm not sure this matters for you though.

```
3 -> 03
6 -> 06  2-> 02
```

Comment: converting the dates to a yyyy-mm-dd format worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, use a more standard date format.

Then, if you want a general answer, then use two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_orders, count(*), min(`buyer-email`), max(`buyer-email`)
from (select a.`buyer-email`,
             count(distinct a.`amazon-order-id`) as num_orders
      from amazon a
      where a.`purchase-date` >= '2014-01-01' and
            a.`purchase-date` < '2015-01-01'
      group by a.`buyer-email`
     ) a
group by num_orders
order by num_orders;
```

Comment: thanks will try tomorrow morning when I'm at my work computer.